# Correct passwords keep appearing as incorrect

Tags: login, user-registration, password, signup

I don't know why passwords are not working... Every time a user registers on my website, their accounts are verified easily but the same passwords they use to register appear as incorrect.

I have disabled my cache plugin and it doesn't matter whether they register from udija.com/login or udija.com/my-account... The passwords still appear as incorrect and I don't know why

If Users reset passwords it works but initial passwords used for registration don't work at all

I'm fed up at this point

Comment: Have you tried replicating the issue with all plugins disabled? If that helps, maybe try activating them one by one and checking which one causes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this... It turned out to be BuddyPress but I don't know why exactly... Everything became fine when I disabled BuddyPress